# Activate jquery Ajax on click on list and pull number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code that I have built from several different pieces of information online:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/qKyNL/6/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Fadeout the existing content
        $('#content').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        // TO DO: Load in new content
        // Scroll to top
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '0px'
        }, 300);
        // TO DO: Change URL
        // TO DO: Set number as active class
    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
        if (t === "timeout") {
            alert("Request timeout");
        } else {
            alert('Request error');
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        // Fade in content
        $('#content').fadeTo(500, 1);
    },
});
```

My question is, how do I trigger the ajax request from clicking on one of the pagination list links (like 1 or 2) whilst using e.prevent default so it is degradable (it will still work if JavaScript is disabled). I guess what I am trying to do is the following in pseudo code:

1. Listen for a click of the pagination link
2. Grab the number of the link clicked (ie was 1 or 2 clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).attr('href');//get the pg=1 value on the href
    alert(number);
    //ajax here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, however something like this should work:

```
$(function() {
    var clicks = {};
    var sendAjax = function(href) {
        //do something with href
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend: function () {
                // Fadeout the existing content
                $('#content').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                // TO DO: Load in new content
                // Scroll to top
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: '0px'
                }, 300);
                // TO DO: Change URL
                // TO DO: Set number as active class
            },
            error: function (x, t, m) {
                if (t === "timeout") {
                    alert("Request timeout");
                } else {
                    alert('Request error');
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                // Fade in content
                $('#content').fadeTo(500, 1);
            },
        });
    };
    $('a').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        clicks[href] = clicks[href] ? clicks[href] + 1 : 1;

        sendAjax(href);
        return false; //disable the link
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just set an onclick on those link 1 and link 2?

ex:

```
link1.click(function() {
  // do stuff with the ajax    
});
```